# Time estimate to location in Today's view?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I found an article (can't remember where) that there's an option to show time estimate of arrival at a location in the Today's view, with regards to traffic too.

How do I enable this option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are referring to the following section:

[image]
[image]

To enable, you need to go to **Settings** → **Privacy** → **Location Services** → **System Services** and turn **Frequent Locations** on. Then go to **Settings** → **Notification Center** and turn **Next Destination** on.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't have the 'Next Destination' option

Comment: @Render The feature is not available on all iPhones (the iPhone 4 doesn't have it, and I'm not sure about the 4s). Which iPhone do you have?

Comment: The iPhone 5S with latest ios7

Comment: @Render Did you already have the Frequent Locations feature enabled? From some Apple Support Communities discussions, if it hasn't been enabled, it'll take some time to gather data before the option will show in Notification Center settings.

Comment: Can you please direct me to that source ? And no I just turned it on

Comment: @Render [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23110495#23110495). Maybe wait a bit for it to get frequent locations?

Comment: It does take awhile for it to start displaying your next destination. I noticed it for church a few weeks after I upgraded to iOS 7. Even sooner, though, it learned my home, and when I was out it would provide an estimated time to go home.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Been 20 days now and no frequent locations have been saved yet ...

Comment: @render, That is strange. I haven't had to troubleshoot my phone so I'm not sure I would have any ideas regarding fixing it. I'm sure that you have all the relevant location services enabled.